# Consider a communication source that transmits packets containing digitized speech...

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Consider a communication source that transmits packets containing digitized speech. After each transmission, the receiver sends a message indicating whether the transmission was successful or unsuccessful. If a transmission is unsuccessful, the packet is re-sent. Assume that the results of succesive transmissions are independent of one another and that the probability of any particular transmission being successful is $p= 0.9$ Let $X$ = # times a packet is transmitted till success.

**a. Determine the probability function of the random variable $X$ = # times a packet is transmitted**

Wouldn't this just be $X(0.9) = 1$ & $X(0.1) = 0$

**b. Find $P(X=4)$**

Not really sure how to do this one. We can use probability calculators but my mind is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a, $X$ can only take values $1,2,3,\dots$ as it is the number of transmissions.  Since the packet gets through with probability $0.9$ (and presumably the acknowledgement is always successful) $P(X=1)=0.9$  You are supposed to find a formula for $P(X=n)$.  Then for b, you just plug $4$ for $n$ in your formula.

Comment: would $P(X = n) = n*0.9$ work?

Comment: Thus $P(X = 4) = 4*0.9 = 3.6$?

Comment: No, probabilities must be less than $1$.  For $X=2$ you have to fail the first transmission and succeed the second.

Comment: So isn't there a 10% chance that i will fail the first and succeed the second?

Comment: That is the chance that you fail the first.  You are not guaranteed to succeed the second try.

Comment: $P(X=0)=1-p$, $P(X=n)=p$ ?

Comment: So $P(X=4) = 0.9$ ?

Comment: No, all the probabilities have to add to $1$.  We have already accounted for $0.9$ with the chance that $X=1$.  As I said, the chance that $X=2$ is the chance that you fail the first try (chance=0.1) and then that you succeed the second try (chance =0.9).  What does that come out?

Comment: So you're saying $P(X=1) = 0.9$ so $P(X=2) = 0.1 * 0.9 = 0.09$

Comment: That is correct.  Can you do $P(X=3)$ and then $P(X=n)?$

Comment: Wow I'm so stupid. So that would mean $P(X=n) = (0.1)^{n-1} * (0.9)$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Ross. Idk why it took me so long to get something so trivial